# Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}{\sin(x^2)}x^{-1/2} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{ \sqrt{x}} $$
(1) $$-1 \le \sin(x^2) \le 1 $$
$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x}} \le \frac{\sin(x^2)}{\sqrt{x}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
(2) I prove that $\lim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = 0$ using the delta definition  
(3) $$0 \le \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{\sqrt{x}} \le 0$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{\sqrt{x}} =0$$
Have I solved this correctly?

Comment: There is no $n$ in the expression of which you are taking a limit.

Comment: Tip: Common functions like $\sin$ and $\log$ can be written as `\sin` and `\log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have to state clearly what you know, what the target conclusion is and write a chain of deductions were each step is either trivial or supported by reference to a known theorem.

While used by many textbooks, I must caution you against the application of the $\lim$ notation. The bare statement:

> Find $$\underset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}
> \frac{\sin(x^2)}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

obscures the fact that we must accomplish *two* goals. Specifically, we must show that the limit exists *and* we must compute the value. Beyond doubt, this point is made *once* somewhere in every textbook, but important points should be repeated.

Moreover, the notation fails to *explicitly* identify the range of valid $x$ values.

I will now demonstrate how to avoid these issues completely. Let $f : (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by
$$ f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{\sqrt{x}}.$$
We must show that
$$ f(x) \rightarrow 0, \quad x \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \in (0, \infty).$$
To that end, we observe that
$$ \forall x \in (0,\infty) \: : \: -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \leq f(x) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.$$
Here we have used $$-1 \leq \sin(x^2) \leq 1,$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Since
$$ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \rightarrow 0, \quad x \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \in (0,\infty),$$
and
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \rightarrow 0, \quad x \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \in (0,\infty),$$
the Squeeze Lemma allows us to conclude that
$$ f(x) \rightarrow 0, \quad x \rightarrow \infty, \quad x \in (0,\infty).$$
This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly correctly.

You need to delete $(3)$ because it's unnecessary and

you need to say also that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)=0$$

Comment: Why is (3) wrong?

Comment: @Aemilius Sorry, I meant $(3)$ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

- I believe you mean $\lim \limits_{\color{red}x \to \infty}$
- In $(2)$, write $\lim \limits_{\color{red}{x \to \infty}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$
- In $(3)$,
  Since $$\color{red}{\lim_{x \to \infty}}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x}} \le \color{red}{\lim_{x \to \infty}}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{\sqrt{x}} \le \color{red}{\lim_{x \to \infty}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Hence, the conclusion.

Summary: Do not omit the limit.

Comment: I'm not sure the red limits should be inserted. There's a lack of English words in the proposed proof to know what's intended to be going on, but it _could_ just be stating the _assumption_ necessary for using the squeeze theorem, in which case the inequalities should hold for every $x$, rather than in the limit.

Comment: Ah, I answered before the limit was inserted in the middle of $0 \leq \frac{\sin(x^2)}{\sqrt{x}} \leq 0$ of which it wasn't true for all $x$. I included $"in (3)" in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Basiclly the limit is zero, cause the limit lays between two limits and both of them are equal to zero. (it is a theorem)